# org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound.handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported Request method 'GET' not supported

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I am trying to use AJAX to communicate with the server asynchronously. However, I am getting the following error message, Any idea?:

> org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound.handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported
>   Request method 'GET' not supported

Controller:

```
package com.math.mvc;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class PiCalculatorController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/picalculator", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String piCalculator(@RequestParam(value = "precision") int pr, @RequestParam(value = "decimals") int de) {
        return String.valueOf(pr * de);
    }
}
```

Javascript:

```
var getPiCalculation;
$(document).ready(function () {
    getPiCalculation = function () {
        if ($('#precision').val() != '' || $('#decimals').val() != '') {
            $.getJSON(
                "picalculator",
                {
                    precision: $('#precision').val(),
                    decimals: $('#decimals').val()
                },
                function (data) {
                    alert("response received: " + data);
                }
            );
        } else {
            alert("Both fields need to be populated!!");
        }
    };
```

Headers:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have just seen on the headers screenshot that the response content-type is set to text/html. This needs to be set to application/json.

Solution:

It is required to add on the @RequestMapping:

> produces = "application/json"

So the controller needs to be changed as follows.

Controller:

```
package com.math.mvc;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class PiCalculatorController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/picalculator", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public @ResponseBody String piCalculator(@RequestParam(value = "precision") int pr, @RequestParam(value = "decimals") int de) {
        return String.valueOf(pr * de);
    }
}
```

After this you will get in the headers the following:

[image]